# Regex to allow numeric values between[1-100] and a percentage symbol

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin.forms

I want a regex to allow numeric values between 1 to 100 and one percentage symbol

Valid samples: 
0%,
100%,
100,
0,
65%

Invalid samples: 101, 101%, 100.1, 65.6%, 65.6

Any help is appreciated

Comment: why not do it in code if you dont know how to use regex?

Comment: by numeric values, do you mean integers only? or can there be a decimal place?

Comment: Can you share your current effort/regex and some valid/invalid samples?

Comment: @sticky bit that would match 0%

Comment: @steve16351: Right, I missed that the lower bound isn't zero. Correction: Something like `^([1-9]\d{0,1}|100)%)$` should do if we talk about integers only.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow. Go to (f.e.) http://regex101.com and experiment until your regex work ...

Answer (score 1):

i dont speak regex but you saied any help would be appreciated so here i go:

```
    bool Verify(string input)
    {
        input = input.Replace("%", "");  // if it contains % remove it
        int value;
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out value))   //if the input can be converted into a number
        {
            if (value > 1 && value < 100)  //and the value is in range
            {
                return true;  //return true to confirm it
            }
        }
        return false;  //in any other case return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(0*100{1,1}\.?((?<=\.)0*)?%$)|(^0*[1-9]\d{0,1}\.?((?<=\.)\d*)?%)$
```

It will allow `65%` and `100%` and discard `65` and `100.1%`

Comment: This matches 0%, in the question as it stands this is unambiguously not allowed.

Comment: @steve16351 you're absolutely right. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Matches a percentage between 0 and 100 (inclusive). Accepts up to 2 decimal places.
ex: 0% , 100% , .17%

```
  ^( 100(?:\.0{1,2})? | 0*?\.\d{1,2} | \d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})? )% $
```

Comment: This matches numbers < 1% which isn't what the OP requested, and you should remove the additional spacing as it doesn't work at all otherwise.